# Change data-percent in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a program in JS in order to change some data-percent when you click on a region of a map. Basically I'm using a jqvmap as Map and a progressbar to display some info for each region that the user clicks.
that what I'm working with:

HTML

```
<h1>Edificable surface</h1>
      <div class="skillbar clearfix" data-percent="0%">
      <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #27ae60;"><span>Job</span></div>
      <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #2ecc71;"></div>
      <div class="skill-bar-percent">100%</div>
      </div> <!-- End Skill Bar -->
```

JavaScript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.skillbar').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).find('.skillbar-bar').animate({
      width:jQuery(this).attr('data-percent')
    },6000);
  });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
          map: 'europe_en',
          enableZoom: false,
          showTooltip: true,
          onRegionClick: function (element, code, region) {
            if (!touch_detect()) {
              // we're not on a mobile device, handle the click
              var message = 'You clicked "' + region + '" which has the code: ' + code.toUpperCase();
              document.getElementById('indi').innerHTML = 'You clicked "' + region + '".';
            }
            if (region == 'United Kingdom') {
            document.getElementByClassName('skillbar clearfix').setAttribute('data-percent', '50%');
          } else {
            document.getElementByClassName('skillbar clearfix').setAttribute('data-percent', '0');
          }
          },
          onRegionOver: function (element, code, region) {
            if (touch_detect()) {
              /// we're not on a mobile device, handle the click
              var message = 'You clicked "' + region + '" which has the code: ' + code.toUpperCase();
              document.getElementById('indi').innerHTML = 'You clicked "' + region + '".';
            } 
        },
        });
      });
```

the first if statement works properly and every time I click on a region it display the region that I have clicked but the second one ( if region = 'United Kingdom')..... " doesn't work even if it looks like correct.
Do you have any tips for me?
Thanks :)

Comment: Could you make a working snippet of your problem? and include relevant code (html, css, jquery)

Comment: Try to create a fiddle example link so that we can check and let you know the solution

Comment: [link]https://jsfiddle.net/gkdk29db/
This is part of the code...Is quite difficult to put all the code because there is the map that has a lot of code.. I took the map from here 
[link]https://github.com/manifestinteractive/jqvmap
I hope it make sense!

Comment: what exactly you mean by `if (region == 'United Kingdom')` doesn't work? Does it mean that execution not going inside that `if` condition? OR statement within that `if` condition is not getting executed properly?

Comment: @vijayP basically when you click, for example, on United Kingdom on the map, the program display "You clicked on 'United Kingdom":
onRegionClick: function (element, code, region) {
            if (!touch_detect()) {
              var message = 'You clicked "' + region + '" which has the code: ' + code.toUpperCase();
              document.getElementById('indi').innerHTML = 'You clicked "' + region + '".';

This part of code works properly.
The second part, the one I use to change the setting of the bar, not! when I esecuted it, it remains on 0% wich is the default value.

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```html
<div id="chart" class="chart-circle" data-percent="100"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```js
var value = 50;
$("#chart").attr("data-percent", value.toString());
```